# Is there a way to run external program in a opera widget or extension? And about its encoding problem in Linux

Tags: javascript, browser, opera, userjs

I'm working on an extension which must be able to call a external program.
In firefox, nsIProcess can be used and it's very easy.
But opera's UserJS or widget seems very weak and have no such function.
Is there some working around?

Another question, I tried to use protocols handlers.
It's just weird, and strange problems show up.

1. When the URL passed to the protocol handler has UTF-8 character like %AE in it,
   whether escape() it or not, the handler cannot receive the correct URL. 
   I have to replace % with some strange strings to avoid this. It's really a ugly solution.
   It only appears in Linux, opera 11.0. 
   I'm starting to think it's a bug.
2. In Opera Linux, it will replace all the backslash in URL with '/'.
   I don't want this, how to disable it?

Comment: There's an open feature request for nsIProcess on the extension api wishlist: http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/782602?t=1292930320&page=1#comment7485122 Maybe it will come some day.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second part of your question, have you tried using the encodeURI() function for escaping your URLs?

Comment: Yep, tried that. I misspoke on the question. In fact, escape() works find, but it's not the standard form of URL since it's in unicode like %uXXXX, besides this, neither of encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() works.